# Is there a way that can allow me to view who are the sharepoint online admins inside our office 365 server

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, office-365, administration

I am working on a new Office 365 project with a new customer.and they send us a user name/password and when i login to the office 365 i find that i have access to every things in sharepoint and also in office 365.Now i was able to create new site collections, remove site collection, access existing site collections which are created on the root url.

so now i believe i am being granted at-least as sharepoint online administrator if not global administrator. but my question is how i can check who have the following permissions on the office 365 also:-

1. who are defined as sharepoint online admin?
2. how are defined as global admin ?

as i need to know who can have full access on the site collections which i am planning to build? 
Thanks

Answer (score 6):

If you are an Global Admin yourself, you can use the default User Management dashboard of Office 365. Navigate to:

**Admin -> Users -> Active Users -> Filter the view to view the users with the admin role.**

Also you can use a PowerShell script to retrieve the administrators.

---

Users with the User Management role are not able to create users with privileges. Only Global Admins can assign admin roles to users.

Comment: I checked the Views list inside the Active Users Page, and seems it contain many options such as; Global admins,Service Admins, user management admin & password admins. so which on i should worry about? now for example inside the global admin i find our user defined and also another admin which is the user who created our user name. now this user is our customer IT manager, so it is a trusted person. but i find a user who is  defined inside the Service Admin, Password Admin & also inside the user management admin.. so will this user gain access to sharepoint sites and have full control?

Comment: can you advice please on my above point ?

Comment: Users in the Password Admin, Service Admin and User Management Admin section do not by default have permissions to access SharePoint sites. Unless you set them as site collection owner in the SharePoint Admin Center of course, or give them Full Contol using Site Permissions inside the Site Collection.

Comment: Ok thanks. i got your point. so the only users i should be worried about are the global admins + sharepoint online admins? as those group of users will have full control over the sites, is this correct? second question about this scenario which i am not sure if it is valid or not:- let say a user who is defined inside the user management admin, create a new user, then will he

Comment: be able to grant the new user a sharepoint admin role or global admin role? if this scenario is valid then users with user management admin role can get access to all the site collection indirectly but creating new user and grant the user SP admin role or global admin role? is this a valid scenario?

Comment: can u advice on my above 2 comments please ?